# Reading Excel file dynamically in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, blank-line

I am trying to read an excel which has some blank rows as well as columns. The process becomes more complicated as it has some junk values before the header as well.

[image]

Currently, I am hardcoding a column name to extract the table.  This has two drawbacks what if the column is not present in the table and what if the column name repeats in the column value. Is there a way to dynamically write a program that automatically detects the table header and reads the table?

snippet of the code:

```
raw_data = pd.read_excel('test_data1.xlsx','Sheet8',header=None)

data_duplicate = pd.DataFrame()

for row in range(raw_data.shape[0]): 
    for col in range(raw_data.shape[1]):
        if raw_data.iloc[row,col] == 'Currency':
            data_duplicate = raw_data.iloc[(row+1):].reset_index(drop=True)
            data_duplicate.columns = list(raw_data.iloc[row])
            break
data_duplicate.dropna(axis=1, how='all',inplace=True)
data_duplicate
```

[image]

Also, the number of bank rows + garbage rows before the header is not fixed.

Comment: You can use `pd.read_excel('test_data1.xlsx', 'Sheet8', skiprows=5)`.

Comment: the number of bank rows + garbage rows before the header is not fixed.

Comment: there is a feature in pyjanitor - remove_empty(), which will remove all the empty rows and columns. alternatively, you could use df.dropna(how='all',axis=0).dropna(how='all',axis=1). the janitor function makes it cleaner.  detecting the header is another matter. if id is part of the header, you could write code, that looks for the first row that has id, and assign that row to the columns. again, janitor has a feature called row_to_names, that can help with that.  https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html. Try out my suggestions. let's see if it works. Excel can be frustrating sometimes.

Comment: Just an addition : as much as possible, avoid iteration

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way: You can drop all rows and all columns containing Nan

```
data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
data = data.dropna(how='all', axis = 1)
data = data.dropna(how='all', axis = 0)
data = data.reset_index(drop = True)
```

better if you put it into a function if you need to open multiple DataFrame in the same code:

```
data = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

def remove_nans(df):
    x = df.dropna(how = 'all', axis = 1)
    x = x.dropna(how = 'all', axis = 0)
    x = x.reset_index(drop = True)
    return x

df = remove_nans(data)
print(df)
```